# How to return value of an attribute in jquery filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

How do i return the value of matched attribute using jquery filter function? I tried below it returned an object not the value of the attribute.

```js
  var htmlBlock = '<div data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER" data-user-mode-key="b577ghf"></div>';  
    if(htmlBlock.match("data-user-mode") && htmlBlock.match("CURRENT_MODE_USER")){
     var matching = $(htmlBlock).filter(function(){
      return $(this).attr('data-user-mode-key');
     });
     $("input#indexMode").val(matching);
     console.log("matching", matching);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Based on single `attr`

```js
var htmlBlock = '<div class="row"><div data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER" data-user-mode-key="b577ghf"></div>hello<p>hi</p><div></div><div>';  
        if(htmlBlock.match("data-user-mode") && htmlBlock.match("CURRENT_MODE_USER")){
         var matching = $(htmlBlock).attr('data-user-mode-key');
         $("input#indexMode").val(matching);
         console.log("matching", matching);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `htmlBlock` in your code?

Comment: @KoshVery The above html line

Comment: Where is it defined in your js code?

Comment: Filter is going to return the objects, not the attr value.  That's the point of filter.  The filter method returns a boolean to determine if the element should be returned as a filtered result.

Comment: Filter is looking for a boolean to determine if the object should be returned.  I believe what you are looking for is $.map

Comment: @bhmahler how do i use map the get the value then?

Comment: Given that the variable only contains one element, there is no point in using map or filter or anything.  Just parse it and grab the attribute

Comment: Would you expect multiple matches? If so, what would you want to put as the value then?

Comment: @Taplar my question is using on `attr` to grab the value, will it work on large html block?

Comment: What do you mean "large"?  The size of a single html element is irrevelent in regards to grabbing one of it's attributes.

Comment: @Taplar i have just updated my question about what i mean

Comment: `$(htmlBlock).find('div').attr('data-user-mode-key');`  The attribute is on the nested div, not the outer div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML could have several elements having that attribute or the attribute is in a nested element, then proceed like this:

```js
var htmlBlock = '<div data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER" data-user-mode-key="b577ghf"></div>';
var $matches = $("<div>").append(htmlBlock).find("[data-user-mode=CURRENT_MODE_USER]");
var values = $.map($matches, function(elem) {
    return $(elem).attr("data-user-mode-key");
});
if (values.length) {
    // Uncomment if you need to put this array as string in an input box
    // $("input#indexMode").val(values);
    console.log("matching", values);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `filter`, just get the `attr`:

```js
var htmlBlock = '<div data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER" data-user-mode-key="b577ghf"></div>';
if (htmlBlock.match("data-user-mode") && htmlBlock.match("CURRENT_MODE_USER")) {
  var matching = $(htmlBlock).attr('data-user-mode-key');
  $("input#indexMode").val(matching);
  console.log("matching", matching);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Finding several items requires parsing `htmlBlock` to DOM:

```js
var htmlBlock = `
<div data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER" data-user-mode-key="aaaaaa"></div>
<div data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER" data-user-mode-key="bbbbbb"></div>
<div data-user-mode="NO_CURRENT_MODE" data-user-mode-key="cccccc"></div>
`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlBlock, 'text/html');

doc.querySelectorAll('[data-user-mode="CURRENT_MODE_USER"]')
  .forEach(e => console.log("matching", e.getAttribute('data-user-mode-key')));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Peter, If you want to get several attributes it will be more tricky. Please provide an example of the larger block.